# How to call manually the onchange event of fileupload control with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a web page with file upload controller an image.

```
 <img src='#' id='imageId' alt='your image' height='64' width='64' src='placeholder.png' class='placeholder' >

 <input type='file' id='myID' onchange='previewImage(this)' accept='image/*' data-thumbnail='imageId'>
```

Actually above HTML code is derived from my asp code.

Ok..Now what I want to do is generate these two components with manual coding.
So I start like this.

```
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image preview = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    preview.ID = "imageId";
    preview.Height = 64;
    preview.Width = 64;

    FileUpload tt = new FileUpload();
    tt.ID = "myID";
```

But there are some attributes remaining in the original HTML code.I do not know exactly how to implement them with C# code.
Further for the "onchange" event of the File upload control have to be implemented.
"previewImage(this)" is javascript function which I used to preview the selected image.
Sp please help me to solve these things with c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

```
tt.Attributes["onchange"] = "previewImage(this)";
```

Comment: How I set data-thumbnail='imageId' ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
tt.Attributes.Add("onchange", "previewImage()");
```

Comment: with the previewImage() I need to pass the parameter "this"..How can I do it?

Comment: hmmmm its hard but i dont think this will work, create a new function like `sampleFunction()` inside that function call `previewImage(this)`. Im just guessing but might work. so in your server side code. you will just add the new function `tt.Attributes.Add("onchange", "sampleFunction()");`

Comment: Ok do you any idea about how to set data-thumbnail='imageId'

Comment: Just try to add the attribute 
`tt.Attributes.Add("data-thumbnail", "imageId");`

Comment: So actually what is the value of "this" parameter?Is it the file selected or something else?

Comment: instead of using **sampleFunction()** and calling  **previewImage(this)** ,directly use **previewImage(this)** it will work.

Comment: @sharad yes (y) referring to js

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you...

**javascript**

```
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        function previewImage(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader(); 

            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imageId').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
 </script>  


<img src='#' id='imageId' alt='your image' height='64' width='64' class='placeholder' >
<input type='file' id='myID' onchange='previewImage(this)' >
```

to call this function in c#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:previewImage(input); ", true);
```

Comment: Exactly same javascript I have used.But what I want is call this function with C# code.So I need to create Fileupload control and image manually with c# code.

Comment: means when you want to call ? any specific control ?

Comment: to call this function in c# u have to add this..ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:previewImage(input); ", true);

Comment: Actually I created File upload controller  and the Image manually with C# code as in the above.
So now what I want is when I choose the image preview should be displayed in image box..Thats what I wanted to do with manual coding